# Do we need the preposition 'in' before black and white?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Do the following two sentences have the same meaning? Or which one is correct?

> 1. The Chinese ink painting is usually in black and white.
> 2. The Chinese ink painting is usually black and white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we use 'in' before a word or phrase when talking about works of art, we are referring to how they were made or produced. If we say that a Chinese ink drawing is 'in' black and white, we are saying that it was done on white paper using black ink. A drawing could be in pencil, in pen and ink, in crayon, in charcoal, etc. A painting could be in oil paint ('oils'), in watercolour, in acrylic (paint), and so on. A sculpture could be in marble, in wood, in plaster.

We can write words in ink, pencil, crayon, chalk, etc.

If we leave out 'in', and say that something such as a Chinese ink painting 'is black and white', we are talking about its appearance.